# WPF ItemSource DataGrid TreeViewItem extra row bug

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, treeviewitem

I am seeing a strange behavior: I have a TreeViewItem bound to a source with multiple rows like so:

```
<TreeViewItem Name="TreeViewItem1" >                                    
    <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding IP,FallbackValue=BindingError,Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
</TreeViewItem>
```

Bound at run time with this code:

```
TreeViewItem1.ItemsSource = MySource;
```

So far it works as expected: Say I have 2 rows in MySource - the TreeViewItem shows 2 child nodes with correct values filled in.
I then later bind a DataGrid in the similar way to the same source:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="0" Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IP" Binding="{Binding IP}" Header="IP" />
        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="Port" Binding="{Binding Port}" Header="Port" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

with code behind

```
MyDataGrid.Items.Clear();
MyDataGrid.ItemsSource = MySource;
```

DataGird has 3 rows: 2 from MySource with correct values filled in and one more for adding rows.

THE PROBLEM: is that at that point the TreeViewItem ALSO gets a 3d child even though MySource still only has 2. It makes no sense but that's what I see. As if both DatGrid and TreeViewItem were bound not to MySource but to some internal structure mimicking it that is shared between the 2 controls.

Probably irrelevant, but for the record MySource is an ObservableCollection with each element implementing INotifyPropertyChanged so adding/removing rows as well as changing values for each row is properly updated on both controls. The only problem is the extra row in TreeViewItem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting:

```
CanUserAddRows="False"
```

To your data grid? I have always set that and then used a button to add rows to my data grids. From my perspective, that makes more sense for our business users.

If that doesn't work for you, you could also not bind your datagrid and treeview to the same observable collection and then keep the tree view observable collection in sync.

**Another Edit**
This still isn't a perfect solution, but your question piqued my interest. I am still a fan of user's clicking buttons to add items ;). Here is what I found.

If I set the TreeViewItem source to a collection view like so:

Window Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Background="Red" >
<Window.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="TreeViewCollection" Source="{Binding AllRoles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="57*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="125*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="138*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TreeViewItem Name="TreeViewItem1" Background="White" Grid.RowSpan="3" IsExpanded="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Source ={StaticResource TreeViewCollection}}">
        <TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ip,FallbackValue=BindingError,Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeViewItem>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="2" Name="MyDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CanUserDeleteRows="True" CanUserAddRows="True"
              ItemsSource="{Binding AllRoles, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="IP" Binding="{Binding ip}" Header="IP" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Code Behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Role> AllRoles { get; private set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        var allRoles = new ObservableCollection<Role>();
        allRoles.Add(new Role{ip = "bob"});
        allRoles.Add(new Role{ip = "john"});
        this.AllRoles = allRoles;

        TreeViewItemSource = GetNonsCollectionView(allRoles);
    }

    public CollectionView DataGridViewSource { get; private set; }
    public CollectionView TreeViewItemSource { get; private set; }

    public CollectionView GetNonsCollectionView(ObservableCollection<Role> nonsList)
    {
        return (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(nonsList);
    }
}

public class Role : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string ip { get; set; }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

}

You will see this working. The issue I see at present is updating the collection view when the user adds a new row to the grid by setting focus. I am tired, or else I would delve further.

Here are some links I found along the way.

[MSFT Employee Comments on similar issue](http://wpf.codeplex.com/discussions/67248) seems like my second solution above is ok by her.

[Guy on MSFT forum describes issue](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c62f3104-574a-4289-9381-b04ede9ba22a/hide-the-newitemplaceholder-in-treeview)

I always thought I was decent at WPF, I had no clue....

Comment: No because I want users to add rows. Which should be clear from my question since I am acknoledging DataGrid having the extra row and only objecting to TreeViewItem getting one ALSO.

Comment: You can add a button that will add a row to your grid so that the user can fill out the appropriate information. Same with deleting rows. APOLOGIES on misreading the intent of your question.

Comment: I tinkered a bit and found exactly what you were talking about. Point stands that setting CanUserAddRows="False" fixes the issue. Adding a button that adds a new Item to your datagrid will still allow your users to add rows.

Comment: Sorry, but I still don't see it as a fix. At least not in a sense that it answers my question in a meaningful way. Sure I could handle the add operation myself (rather than let DataGrid do it) I could also use another control. Which is incidentally what I am currently doing. I figured if Add is done via extra button then the Delete should be too and if I am doing it all by hand what's the point of DataGrid so I downgraded to ListView.

Comment: I think offering a work around to a problem can be useful, but in this case I feel the problem is not really addressed. After all the default behavior of the DataGrid is - extra row enabled and if it's broken in this significant way in its default state it's a pretty big deal. Can somebody explain this behavior in some way? Is this a bug that should be reported to Microsoft? Has it already been reported?

Comment: Understand completely I wish I knew more, I did some research and posted some findings. Hope they help you along the way!